# need to search a value in a text file then extract line where value is in from text file python3x

Tags: python, list, pdfminer

I have a large text file I need to search its lines and if a certain value is in the line pull the line and store it in a list

when i try to use a for loop it does not go line by line but rather character by character to check it 
I really don't want to use the loops cause the files are very big so if you guys have any idea how to search a text file find a value and then extract the entire line this value was in. 
s='''
****************** ON LOCATION************************************************************************
** MATERIAL PROGRAM+ SH MUD LOGGING CABIN UML111 + ORS MUD CABIN & WM CABIN
 ** G ENERGY 4"3/4 DRILLING JAR QN 475-0029
**86 JTS 4" 1/2 TUBING 13,5# P110 N VAM + 44 jtsTBG 2" 7/8 6.4# N80 N.VAM + 2 PUP JTS 13'' 3/8 68# N80 BTC + 1 PUP JTS 7'' 32# P110 N.VAM+ 70 JTS TUBING 2"3/8 +1 
X-OVER 9"5/8 47# P110 N,VAM PIN X BTC BOX
** BAKER CORING EQUIPMENTS & CREW
'''
code:

```
 def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        retstr = io.StringIO()
        codec = 'utf-8'
        laparams = LAParams()
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
        password = ""
        maxpages = 0
        caching = True
        pagenos = set()

        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,
                                      password=password,
                                      caching=caching,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            interpreter.process_page(page)

        text = retstr.getvalue()

        fp.close()
        device.close()
        retstr.close()
        return text

    path="C:\DDR reports\Smith General server\DDR Algeria\DDR\\07.July\\02.07.2019\\BELN-1-Daily Drilling Report-Report Number51-(07-02-2019).pdf"

    r=convert_pdf_to_txt(path)
        regex=re.compile('[1-9]*\s[a-zA-Z]*\sJar', re.IGNORECASE)
list_jar=list()
i=0
for line in r.split('\n'):
    #search_v=re.findall(pattern,r)
    x=re.findall(regex, line)
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: i am using re to search for specific keywords that follow a pattern but i am not getting any results obviously i am missing something big